# Nested if loops in For Loop in R to compare conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I wanted to compare two conditions & assign a score; I have two vectors one A with some values & B is the timestamp. All I wanted to do is if say value in A is greater than a threshold & the difference in timestamps with its previous one is greater than 1 I should assign a score to C.. I am having trouble executing the following code.

```
for(i in 2:length(test$B)) {
  if(test$A>15 & (test$B[i]-test$B[i-1])<=4) {
    test$C<-3 
  } else if(test$A<15 & (test$B[i]-test$B[i-1]==1)) {
    test$C<-2 
  } else {
    test$C<-1
  } 
}
```

Comment: You need the logical AND operator, which is `&&`, not `&`.  But, you may not even need loops.

Comment: You are probably missing i for test$A and test$C. It needs to be test$A[i] and test$C[i].

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example (just a few lines of data needed) and what the expected output should look like?

Comment: Hi Roman, it is tough to produce a sample output as it is scoring based on few conditions..however let me  try to explain a little further..this below is a sample  B & A are vectors B is time stamp in seconds & A is some value        
     B   A
31585 9
31586 15
31587 18
31622 20
31623 9
31624 6
as you can see the value of A at 31622  time is greater than 15 & also the difference between time 31622 and its previous one is greater than 1 so the score here should be say 3  ..similarly for other conditions....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sample data**

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame( A = sample( 10:20, 100, replace = TRUE ),
                  B = sample( 1:11, 100, replace = TRUE ),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
```

**code - tidyverse/dplyr**

```
library( dplyr )                  

df %>% mutate( C = case_when(
  A > 15 & B - lag( B ) <= 4 ~ 3,
  A < 15 & B - lag( B ) == 1 ~ 2,
  TRUE ~ 1 ) )

#      A  B C
# 1   12  2 1
# 2   13  8 1
# 3   12 11 1
# 4   11  3 1
# 5   19  6 3
# 6   17  9 3
# 7   20  7 3
# 8   16  9 3
# 9   14  4 1
# 10  20  5 3
# 11  20  3 3
# 12  14  4 2
#...
```